# Why do I get compilation error "org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException"?

Tags: java, ant, compilation, jasper-reports

I am trying to compile my JasperReports template using an Ant script and Java. I am getting this error:

```
jasper java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
```

There is nothing complex in the template, but I still can't compile.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You will have to set the `language` value in your template to Java. There are two ways you can do this:

1. If you are using *iReport,* select the root object in your *Report Inspector* (the one with the same name as your report). Then in the *Properties* window, select *Java* from the *Languages* drop-down.
2. If you are editing the raw mark-up in the JRXML file, remove `language="groovy"` from the file altogether.

Then try to recompile - you should be sorted. :)

Comment: Don't forget to compile de .jasper file once .jrxml is modified!

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Maven, you must add the groovy dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

In another case, you must add the library groovy in your lib folder (WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: if you using maven, please check you dont put `<scope>provided</scope>`

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to copy groovy-all-{version}.jar from the groovy binary distribution into the application's.

Comment: Bad solution, as you're merely satisfying a new and unnecessary dependency requirement. In travega's answer you're removing the dependency requirement completely, which is the better way to go.

Comment: This depends on whether you are using groovy expression or not in your report...., switching to java will make your groovy expression as == fail. (note the solution is to copy the libraries from the jasper report distribution (lib) relative to groovy in the classpath)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using TIBCOJaspersoftStudio:

1. Download latest groovy 2.4.* jar from https://groovy.apache.org/download.html
2. Unpack and get this file ./groovy-2.4.10/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.10.jar
3. Put the jar in ./TIBCOJaspersoftStudio-6.3.1.final/plugins
4. Delete the old jar: ./TIBCOJaspersoftStudio-6.3.1.final/plugins/groovy-all_2.4.5.jar

Comment: These steps are what helped me solve this problem.  Care to explain why your answer would be appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Change the languge to java in JRXML (ex:- language="java") or add groovy*.jar to your project’s classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the a important library **groovy** in path.

**case 1 :** if you are using Maven add this dependency with compatible version in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Case 2 :** Second way is add the compatible version of groovy jar in class path

**Url to download groovy jar :**  http://groovy-lang.org/download.html