# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I want to print data stored in the database, I used  ireport and jasperreport,I think that I have a problem with libraries, here the list of libraries which I downloaded:

```
 jasperreports-6.0.4.jar
 jasperreports-font-6.0.4.jar
 jasperreports-javaflow-6.0.4.jar
 barecode4j-2.1.jar
 commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
 commons-codec-1.5.jar
 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
 commons-digester-2.1.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
 iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
 com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar
```

data.html

```
<form action="Print">
<input type="submit" value="print">
</form>
```

Servlet:Print.java

```
  private static Connection con;  
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
 }catch(SQLException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException f){
  f.printStackTrace();
  }  
   try{
        JasperDesign jd= JRXmlLoader.load("list_user.jrxml");
      String sql ="select * from user";
       JRDesignQuery newQuery=new JRDesignQuery();
       newQuery.setText(sql);
       jd.setQuery(newQuery);
       JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
       JasperPrint jasperprint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,con);
       JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperprint);
   }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
   }
```

I had this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:156)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:869)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:357)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:617)
```

Comment: Hi, some guys got into the same situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935925/jasperreports-compilation-error
And also here: http://grails-groovy.blogspot.hu/2009/08/groovy-compilation-problem-while.html
They both say there are language setting problems.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I removed language="groovy" but I had the same error

Comment: You can try language="java" if removing does not work or add jar that support groovy.

Comment: I added groovy 2.0.jar and it worked