# JasperReport not showing after making .jar application

Tags: java, jasper-reports, executable-jar

I made application in JAVA that reads data from CSV to JTable and generate reports from it. Everything works fine after compiling, but **after making .jar** file **reports are not working**. It seems that all libraries are included:[image]

**Fragment of code that generates report:** 
[image]

I also tried to correct it with Input Stream and loadXML like it is described here:
[Jasper report is not working after making jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679230/jasper-report-is-not-working-after-making-jar-file), but then i get an exception:  *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException*

**My main goal is to make usable .jar application (reports must be working)** or at least "a student method" to run app on other computer. How can i achieve it? :)

Error description after running .jar from cmd:

[image]

Comment: run it from cmd.what do you see on the cmd screen?did you forget to set main class?

Comment: @FastSnail It seems that you are close to answer ;) Can You help after seeing error desc from cmd?

Comment: please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935925/jasperreports-compilation-error.it may help you